# function with for a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, eval, apply, processing-efficiency

I have a huge matrix and want to evaluate several expressions on it.

```
lexpr <- sapply(c("col1 > col2", "col1 > col3",  "col2 == 15"), function(x) parse(text=x))
M <- matrix(data=sample(1:100, 30), nrow = 10, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(1:10, c('col1','col2','col3')))
M <- as.data.frame(M)
logi <- with(M, lapply(lexpr, function(x) eval(x)))
```

How to avoid the as.data.frame transformation which takes a lot of time and memory?